# Not able to debug Flutter app on a real device works fine on Emulator

Tags: flutter, dart

[I get this error when trying to debug over USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur74K.png)

Comment: is it access the internet? maybe your ide not connected internet

Comment: @rollcake Will it download the required files in VS code itself? or I will have to download them in Android Studio?

Comment: android studio, menu -> build -> rebuild project so, auto download

Comment: Hi, this Issue was solved after installing the latest Updates for Google USB Drivers from SDK tools in Android Studio. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this Issue was solved after installing the latest Updates for Google USB Drivers from SDK tools in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an internet connection so it can download the required files

Comment: Will it download the required files in VS code itself? or I will have to download them in Android Studio?

Comment: When you run the app, it will automatically start downloading. Doesn't matter if it is in VS Code or AS